# OpenVPN server as it's own CA -- security concerns?

Tags: linux, openvpn, certificate-authority

I was reading the Digital Ocean [guide to setting up an OpenVPN server on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-18-04) in anticipation of doing exactly that, and saw this tidbit:

> Additionally, you will need a separate machine to serve as your
>   certificate authority (CA). While it’s technically possible to use
>   your OpenVPN server or your local machine as your CA, this is not
>   recommended as it opens up your VPN to some security vulnerabilities.
>   Per the official OpenVPN documentation, you should place your CA on a
>   standalone machine that’s dedicated to importing and signing
>   certificate requests.

I've never seen that warning before and have seen plenty of other (e.g. StrongSwan IKEv2) VPN solutions setup on a single server where it is both the VPN listener and the CA in SMB environments. These environments had no other CA, and the VPN server CA's only purpose was for VPN authentication.

Aside from the general rule of thumb that you usually wouldn't want a CA server on the edge of your network/internet accessible, are there other security concerns with an OpenVPN box acting as it's own CA? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the right idea that it basically boils down to the general idea that a CA ought to be made as inaccessible as possible.

Of course, if the VPN server were to be compromised that in itself is probably really bad.
But having the CA elsewhere would at least remove some options for an intruder (like if they were sneaky and went for just copying the CA and then had the ability of creating their own certs offline at any time to gain access), and recovery would not necessitate starting the whole CA setup from scratch, only setting up a clean VPN server.

Also, of course if you were to use the same CA for other purposes (including other VPN servers), the impact is obviously even more direct in that  everything else does not also get compromised with that one VPN server.

The "Per the official OpenVPN documentation" reference in your quoted text probably refers to this paragraph in the [Security section of the OpenVPN Howto](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#security):

> #### Keep the root key (ca.key) on a standalone machine without a network connection
>
> One of the security benefits of using an X509 PKI (as OpenVPN does) is that the root CA key (ca.key) need not be present on the OpenVPN server machine. In a high security environment, you might want to specially designate a machine for key signing purposes, keep the machine well-protected physically, and disconnect it from all networks. Floppy disks can be used to move key files back and forth, as necessary. Such measures make it extremely difficult for an attacker to steal the root key, short of physical theft of the key signing machine.